# Tagging under an equation using underbrace

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I would like to tag two parts of a huge equation using underbraces (and call them, say term A and term B).  Later in the text, I want to talk about term A and term B.  Is there a way to tag and label A and refer to it using ref later?  Currently, I'm having to manually type in A, B, C, etc. and keep referring to
check if I'm referring to the right tag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}_{A}  + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{B}
\end{equation*}

Later in the text, I want to talk about term A and term B.  Is there a
way to tag and label A and refer to it using ref later?  Currently,
I'm having to manually type in A, B, C, etc. and keep referring to
check if I'm referring to the right tag.

\end{document}
```

I want to replace `_{A}` with something like `_{\tag{A}\label{eq:term1}}`.  And then, later in the text say `Term~\ref{eq:term1} is blah blah blah` (where of course, blah blah blah is `$n*(n+1)/2$`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\mytag{<tag>}{<label>}` as defined in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath - loaded by {mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytag}[2]{%
  \text{#1}%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#2}{{#1}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) = 
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}_{\mytag{A}{termA}} + 
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{\mytag{B}{termB}}
\end{equation*}

\newpage

Later in the text, I want to talk about term~\ref{termA} and term~\ref{termB}.
\end{document}
```

You supply the `<tag>` you want to put down for the label, as well as the regular label `<label>`. `\mytag` prints `<tag>` using `\text{<tag>}` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) and then performs the regular label-writing to the `.aux` file (taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)). That allows you to use `\ref{<label>}` to retrieve `<tag>` again.

Note that this does not support usage with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Modifications are required in order for that, but it is doable. Wait for it...

---

...and now with `hyperref` support:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath - loaded by {mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytag}[2]{%
  \text{#1}%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@currentlabelname
    \edef\@currentlabelname{%
      \expandafter\strip@period\@currentlabelname\relax.\relax\@@@%
    }%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#2}{%
        {#1}%
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) = 
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}_{\mytag{A}{termA}} + 
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{\mytag{B}{termB}}
\end{equation*}

\newpage

Later in the text, I want to talk about term~\ref{termA} and term~\ref{termB}.
\end{document}
```

As it stands, these two methods are exclusive. That is, if you want `hyperref` support, the second approach works. If you do not want support for `hyperref`, then you should go with the former.

Comment: Thanks!  That works!  I'll look into hyperref (and cleveref since I use it) source code.  Ideally, I would like "term" to appear automatically when I use \cref{termA}.

Comment: @Maronka: It would be possible to extend this to include usage with `hyperref`. However, adding `term` as part of the reference may be temperamental, since you might want to capitalize at the start of a sentence and sometimes not. Moreover, this is just one way of doing it - there are others.

Comment: Thanks for the hyperref support.  Turns out, using cleveref's macros (see code below) makes life much simpler.  cleveref's macros take care of hyperref support depending on if hyperref has been included.

Answer (score 3):

The natural way to number entities (here terms) is using a counter. The appearance of the counter can be changed from arabic numbers to uppercase letters. If package `hyperref` is loaded, also its `\autoref` feature can be used.

We need only to trick `amsmath` a little. It does not allow multiple labels, but it
accepts the command under a different name. Because `hyperref` loads `nameref`
during `\begin{document}` and that package redefines `\label`, the definition of the alias `\mylabel` for `\label` is delayed using `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{term}
\renewcommand*{\theterm}{\Alph{term}}
\newcommand*{\termautorefname}{term}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mylabel\label
}

\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{%
  \begingroup % keep the effects of \refstepcounter local
    \refstepcounter{term}%
    \mylabel{#1}%
    \text{\theterm}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) =
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}_{\mytag{termA}} +
    \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{\mytag{termB}}
\end{gather*}

\newpage

Later in the text, I want to talk about \autoref{termA} and
\autoref{termB}.
\end{document}
```

This does also work in the new environments of package `amsmath` like `gather` that uses
a two pass system. First the equation is measured, then typeset. Package `amsmath` takes care of the counter settings as long as the counter was defined using `\newcounter`.
The `\label` or the destination by `hyperref`'s `\refstepcounter` is set twice, but
the first tries go into the measuring box that is thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the modified MWE (from the question) along with a solution! (at least what I originally had in mind).  Thanks: @Werner and the authors of cleveref, amsmath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \term definition
% Usage:  \underbrace{<long-expression>}_{\term[optlabel]{labelname}}
% Later on, use \cref{labelname} or \ref{labelname}
% if [optlabel] is missing, a counter (A, B, C, ...) is used.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{termcounter}
\renewcommand{\thetermcounter}{\Alph{termcounter}}
\crefname{term}{term}{terms}
\creflabelformat{term}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}

\makeatletter
\def\term{\@ifnextchar[\term@optarg\term@noarg}%]
\def\term@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \textup{#1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
  \def\cref@currentlabel{[][2147483647][]#1}%
  \cref@label[term]{#2}}
\def\term@noarg#1{%
  \refstepcounter{termcounter}%
  \textup{\thetermcounter}%
  \cref@label[term]{#1}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}

\eject
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}%
    _{\term{termA}} + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{\term[{B but
      actually termC}]{termC}}
\end{equation}
\eject

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}\tag{$\dagger$}
  \sum_{i=1}^n (i + i^2) = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i}%
    _{generic} + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}_{\term[B]{termB}}
\end{equation}

\eject
Later in the text, I want to talk about \cref{termA}, \cpageref{termA}
and \cref{termC}.  Is there a way to say \ref{termA} is a term inside
\cref{eq:1} ?


Is there a \ref{termA}, way to tag and label A and refer to it using
ref later ?  Currently, I'm having to manually type in A, B, C,
etc. and keep referring to check if I'm referring to the right tag.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't add "non answers", but rather edit your original question.

Comment: But it is an answer to the question I posed.  With @Werner's help and a little bit of coding (mostly copy/paste from cleveref.sty and amsmath.sty), I managed to create the command I was asking for.  I thought the answer might help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Maronka It is an answer *now*, but the original version still had some questions in it and I would imagine that that is what egreg is referring to (since his comment dates from that time).  Posting your own answer is absolutely fine, but when there's still stuff you're asking for help with then it is best to edit the original question.  Sometimes it's a fine line!  The point is that people are more likely to see edits to questions and so be thinking how best to help, whereas they assume that answers are answers.

Comment: @AndrewStacey:  Sounds good.  Am new to this website; still learning the ways.  Thanks!