# Use different tags for different terms of the same unlabeled equation

Tags: equations, labels

I have a long equation (but that fits in just one line), with three terms:

```
\begin{equation*}\label{eq:threeterms}
A = \underbrace{A_1}_{(1)} + \underbrace{A_2}_{(2)} + \underbrace{A_3}_{(3)}.
\end{equation*}
```

The equation is not numbered, as it barely fits on the line, and I use hand-written references `$(1)$`, `$(2)$` and `$(3)$` in all the text to refer to the three terms.
I would like to be able to define three (non displayed) tags for the three terms, and refer to them with `\eqref{eq:term1}` (etc), to have a nice link to the equation and not just the text `$(1)$`.

Is this possible? I tried naively with three `\tag{1}`, `\tag{2}` and `\tag{3}` (or `\tag*`) commands but I cannot attain what I would like.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was already answered in this other question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53691/. Sorry for the duplicate question!